# UILabel not visible in circular custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uilabel

My view hierarchy looks like the following, I have a UITableViewController -> Static Cells -> UITableViewCell -> Custom UIView -> UILabel

My goal is to show circular profile image views and the last view shows a count with the number of remaining images.

That's how I create a circular view which works perfectly fine

```
private func getCircularViewForPoint(point: CGPoint) -> UIView {
    var circularView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 30, height: 30))
    circularView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    circularView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    circularView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return circularView
}
```

So now I want to create such a view with a UILabel inside

```
private func getCircularCountViewForPoint(point: CGPoint, maxAmount: Int) -> UIView {
    var circularView = self.getCircularViewForPoint(point)
    circularView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    var label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    label.center = circularView.center
    label.text = "XY"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

//        self.addSubview(label)  // This works but label is now behind circularView of course

    circularView.addSubview(label)

    return circularView
}
```

The outcome looks like this, with no UILabel in the brown view.

[image: The UILabel is not visible inside the brown UIView]

Frame of `circularView`:
`<UIView: 0x7feb28fd9d50; frame = (295 24.75; 30 30); clipsToBounds = YES; ...`

Frame of `label`:
`<UILabel: 0x7feb28ce33b0; frame = (295 24.75; 30 30); userInteractionEnabled = NO; ...`

The weird thing is, if I put this code into a playground, it works like expected and the label is visible.

Just for completeness that's how I call these two functions

```
for var i = 0; i < maxAmount-1; i++ {
    self.addSubview(self.getCircularViewForPoint(CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)))
    xPos += size+offset
}

// add count view
var countView = self.getCircularCountViewForPoint(CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), maxAmount: maxAmount)
self.addSubview(countView)
```

Comment: remove **label.center = circularView.center**

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much. Any idea why this was causing this issue?

Comment: circularView.center gives center point of circularView with respect to its superView and when you set labe.center then its center point moves to that point

Comment: which shouldn't be wrong I would say, as you see the frames are the same, therefore their center point should also be the same.

Comment: NO because you are adding label to circularView not main view

Comment: label with move to that point in circularView

Comment: if you want label at center of circularVIew try this:    **label.center = CGPoint(x: circularView.frame.width/2, y: circularView.frame.height/2)**

Answer (score 0):

since your goal is to show profile pictures i would have tried to replace the brown background with the picture:

```
    circularView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "profilepicturename.png")!)
```

sorry i couldn't help with the label thing

Comment: yeah of course, this was just for test purpose, I'm going to replace the `UIView` with an `UIImageView` of course